# Confused about SQLite in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an application which uses a database with multiple tables.
I'm using a common class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, for opening, closing and moving the database, and a class for each table for helper methods (queries on the table). Each of these classes use an object that opens and closes the database.

My question is: where do I have to locate queries that are not specific to a table and access other tables?

Is this approach correct?

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper opens your db for you, so you don't have to do any of that.  All you need to do is put your queries in the subclass and call them.

Comment: My class helpers are not subclass of the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, I just define on each class an object of the class I defined that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Is this wrong? And what about this: I have a class for the table "A", a class for the table "B" and a class for the table "C" (this table has foreigner keys of table A and B). The query "FindAbyB" should be located on class C?

Comment: I wouldn't say your method is wrong, but at the bottom level, you pretty much need to put your queries in a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper.  Your table-specific classes could encapsulate "business logic" to provide a set of "business" methods to your app level.

Comment: I see... thank you very much for your advice. By the way, I followed this guide as reference: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html , take a look to CommentsDataSource class. Thank you again.